# docker stop && docker rm doesn't really get rid of my container

Tags: postgresql, docker, vagrant

I have some weird behaviour when working with the [postgres](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) image.

I've created a script which is mounted into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` and using single-user mode to initialise the database.

However, when I update the script, run

```
docker stop postgres_db
docker rm postgres_db
```

and than start a new container, the database is the old one. It doesn't change.

I'm using vagrant `box-cutter/ubuntu1404-docker` and when I run

```
vagrant destroy -f
vagrant up
```

and than recreate the new docker container, the changes are applied.

Why doesn't it work when I just remove the old container and start a new one? Where does docker keep it's cache which I could purge to really get a new image?

**Update:**

The exact docker file I'm using is a small extension to the original one. It just installs the orafce plugin [link](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/grmanit/postgres/dockerfile/), content:

```
FROM postgres:9.4

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y postgresql-9.4-orafce && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

the command I use to start a new container is:

```
docker run --name="postgres_db" \
           --restart="always" \
           -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=PostgresPassword \
           -p 5432:5432 \
           -v /data:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
           -v /vagrant/container_data/init_scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d \
           -v /vagrant/container_data/tmp:/tmp \
           -d grmanit/postgres
```

the `init_scripts` folder contains one script which creates a new database and a new user.

**Clarifications:**

When I change the script in my `init_scripts` folder, for instance modify the database name, and than stop+remove the old container and start a new one, it doesn't have any effect.

When I change the password of `postgres`, which is set as an environment variable in the `docker run` command (in this example it's `PostgresPassword`) and again stop+remove the old container and than start a new one with the new environment variable, it again doesn't have any effect. I still need to use the old password to connect to the db and the new one wouldn't work.

But when I destroy the VM and start it up again, I have the configurations which I had defined before. However changing them again needs me to destroy and restart the VM which takes much longer than just destroying a docker container and starting up a new one.

Comment: Please include the dockerfile (if any) and the exact command you use to start the container

Comment: One quirk with docker vs VM is that each `docker run` creates a new copy of the original image as a new container, and thus, it appears that changes do not persist.  If that's the problem, learning about mounting volumes for persistent files  with `-v` or perhaps `docker commit` may be helpful (though don't make a habit of that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a new container, but `-v /data:/var/lib/postgresql/data` mounts the `/data` directory of the host into the container, making changes to the database persistent between containers. If you omit that, the database will be isolated in the container and will disappear as soon as you delete the container.

See [Managing data in containers (Docker documentation)](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) for details.